# Get Integer between parenthesis using RegExp

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to use regExp to get values between parenthesis:
for example:

```
<td width=40><input type=\"button\" OnClick='FullScreen(1)' value=\" 1\" size=80></td>
<td width=(40)><input type=\"button\" OnClick='FullScreen(2)' value=\" 1\" size=80></td>
<td width=40><input type=\"button\" OnClick='FullScreen(3)' value=\" 1\" size=80></td>
<td width=40><input type=\"button\" OnClick='FullScreen(4)' value=\" 1\" size=80></td>
```

I want to retrieve the values of the Fullscreen in this case 1,2,3 and 4

I try this regular expression:

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\((.*?)\\)");

    Matcher m = p.matcher(String);
    if(m.find()){
        System.out.println("val = " +m.group(1));
    }
```

but this retrieves all the values between parenthesis how to I make to only get the values from the FullScreen string?

Thanks

Comment: are all 4 lines part of the same String or are they separate Strings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Also add the  `FullScreen` prefix to your regex.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("FullScreen\\((.*?)\\)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(String);
if(m.find()){
    System.out.println("val = " +m.group(1));
}
```